# Show that if $Z\cup E$ is measurable then so is $E.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

**Problem:**

> Let $E,Z \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $Z$ be a set of measure zero. Show that if $Z\cup E$ is measurable then so is $E.$

**What I have done:**

> Since $Z\cup E$ is measurable then there exists 
>   $G$ 
>   such that $Z\cup E\subset G$ **consequently $ E\subset G$.**
>   Also,
>   $\vert G-(Z\cup E) \vert_{e}<\epsilon $
>   But 
>   $Z$ is also zero measure so there exists $G'$ such that
>   $\vert G'-(Z) \vert_{e}<\epsilon $ and $Z\subset G'$
>   But I can't say that 
>   $\vert G-E\vert<\epsilon'$
>   Actually, I have to find an open set like $G$ whcih cantains $E$(which I have done) and $\vert G-E\vert<\epsilon'$

I need just a hint, not the whole solution. Maybe my approach is wrong entirely.

Comment: Shashi has given a nice solution. In case you want to proceed with your approach, can you clarify what the goal is? Certainly you can't prove that $E$ is measurable by proving that there is some $G$ with $|G-E| < \epsilon$. For one thing, in order for $|G-E|$ to be defined, you need to already know that $E$ is measurable. What you can try to do is show that there is an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$ and $|G-F| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceed in this way:
According to the **Hint** by @shashi, 
$E=(E\cup Z)\cap (Z\cap E^{c})^{c} $
we know that 
$E\cup Z$ 
is measurable. 
But we know that $(Z\cap E^{c})\subset Z$ and $Z$ is zero measure and our space is Lebesgue measure and consequently being sigma algebra and having completion(every subset of zero measure is of measure zero). 
Therefore, $ Z-E $ is measurable and then $(Z-E)^{c}$ is measurable. Then $E$ is measurable.

Comment: It's not true in general that $(E^c \cap Z^c) \cup Z = Z - E$. The right hand side is contained in $Z$, but the left hand side contains $Z$.

Comment: yes 
you are right. Let me try again

Comment: Dear @Bungo I edited my answer.

Comment: Looks good now!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I suppose you are talking about the Lebesgue measure (tell me if that is not the case). Since $Z$ is a null set, it is measurable. Define the following set:
\begin{align} 
A:=[Z\cup E] \cap [Z\cap E^c]^c
\end{align} 
Now where is the set $A$ equal to? And what can you say about it?

Edit: Thanks to @Bungo for pointing out a set which is more useful than the one I had in mind.

Comment: It might be more useful to look at $(Z \cup E) \cap (Z \cap E^c)^c$.

Comment: @Bungo thanks! I edited it.

Comment: @Shashi thanks for the hint.